# How to assign UniqueID on a table basted on multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am wondering how to create a SQL Query to calculate if the row is unique based on certain columns(in this case InventoryID, CheckoutID, postal code, and UserID) to determine if its the first one that is unique then give it a value 1 if it has occurred again give it a 0.

| Primary Key | StoreID | InventoryID | CheckoutID | Postal Code | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 201 | 301 | 111 | A1 |
| 2 | 101 | 201 | 301 | 111 | A1 |
| 3 | 102 | 202 | 302 | 112 | A2 |
| 4 | 103 | 203 | 303 | 113 | A3 |
| 5 | 104 | 204 | 304 | 114 | A4 |
| 6 | 104 | 205 | 305 | 114 | A4 |
| 7 | 104 | 205 | 305 | 114 | A4 |

I am looking to add a column or out how to get it to look like this:

| Primary Key | StoreID | InventoryID | CheckoutID | Postal Code | UserID | unique |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 201 | 301 | 111 | A1 | 1 |
| 2 | 101 | 201 | 301 | 111 | A1 | 0 |
| 3 | 102 | 202 | 302 | 112 | A2 | 1 |
| 4 | 103 | 203 | 303 | 113 | A3 | 1 |
| 5 | 104 | 204 | 304 | 114 | A4 | 1 |
| 6 | 104 | 205 | 305 | 114 | A4 | 1 |
| 7 | 104 | 205 | 305 | 114 | A4 | 0 |

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are ordering by primary key, you can try this:

```
SELECT
    "Primary Key", StoreID, InventoryID, CheckoutID, "Postal Code", UserID,
    case WHEN row_num = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "unique"
FROM (
    SELECT
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InventoryID, CheckoutID, "Postal Code", UserID ORDER BY "Primary Key") AS row_num
    FROM my_table
) foo;
```